# How do I find which tables are being inserted to? Is there a DMV for that in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In Microsoft SQL Server 2008, how do I find which tables are being inserted to? Is there a DMV for that?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Profiler:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: Or put a DML insert trigger on all tables and log info to an audit table. Or use CDC (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx). Profiler is probably the answer you are looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, all tables can be inserted into -- depending on access.

I think you're really after [SQL Server Audit functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx). The one(s) that have the `user_updates` increased between consecutive checks have seen updates ('updates' in general: inserts, deletes or value updates).

A more detailed view is offered by [`sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx) which can differentiate between the inserts and deletes and between operations occurring at leaf level or at non-leaf level, but such level of detail may be overkill if you only try to find out which tables in your database are still 'used' and which ones are 'dead code'.

Both tables maintain the counts only *since last database startup* so you need to run a representative load first to get an accurate picture.